# 'str' object has not attribute 'subs'

Tags: python, sympy

Here is my Python code written in Vim. Whenever I run it, I get the error `'str' object has not attribute 'subs'`

```
from sympy import *
x,a_test,b_test,fa_test,fb_test=symbols('x a_test b_test fa_test fb_test')
expr=raw_input("enter the equation")
print expr
print "hello"
try:
    print "hello"
    inc=0
    a=inc
    fa=expr.subs(x,inc)
    print "hello"
    if(fa<0):
        print "hello"
        inc+=1
        fb=expr.subs(x,inc)
        if(fb<=0):
            while(fb<=0):
                inc+=1
    else:
        print "hello"
        inc+=1
        fb=expr.subs(x,inc)
        if(fb<=0):
            while(fb<=0):
                inc+=1
    b=inc
    print a
    print b
    print fa
    print fb
except Exception,e:
    print e
```

Comment: What are you expecting `subs` to do? It's not a method of `str`, which `expr` is (as returned from `raw_input`).

Comment: You are probably looking for [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace). Do note that the replacement must be a `str` type also (and not an `int` as defined for `inc`).

Comment: i am expecting from subs to substitute the value of "inc" in place of x in the equation which will be input the user.

Comment: @ArsalanMehmood Please read the [documentation for Python's `str` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)

Comment: i just edited code and replaces expr.subs by expr.replace and also changed the data type of inc from integer to string but it didn`t work for me ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `raw_input` is a `str`; you cannot use it as if it is a SymPy `expr`. You need to [parse](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/parsing.html) it first:

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
...
expr = parse_expr(raw_input("enter the equation"))
```

Comment: Dear Seluck ....'NegativeOne' object has not attribute 'strip'...... what does this mean?

Comment: It must be something to do with your expression. What do you input as the equation?

Comment: see below is my  modified code as u advised me tou put parse_expr thing and i am inputting equation     x**2-x-1

Comment: sorry i am getting some error pasting code here  but the input equation is    x**2-x-1

Comment: It is hard to post code as a comment; can you please post it as another question as this is a different problem?

Comment: yeah ok i am gonna upload it as another question .... then have a look at it plz :) :)

Comment: expr='x**3-x-1'

expr
Out[2]: 'x**3-x-1'

expr.subs(x,0)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-18d3004021e6>", line 1, in <module>
    expr.subs(x,0)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'subs'

Comment: what else can i use to substitute the value in equation?